# function is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an issue with C# in ASP.

I get an error on the following line of code which starts "string[]"....

```
Label DT33 = (Label)MainContent2.FindControl("data_text");

string[] lines = Strings.Split(DT33.Text, "<br>");
num = lines.Length;The error reads....
```

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'System.Linq.Strings' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I have specified the following names space....

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

Along with many others. This is a .net 3.5 app, I am out of ideas at this point.

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you actually mean this:

```
Label DT33 = (Label)MainContent2.FindControl("data_text");

string[] lines = DT33.Text.Split(new string[] {"<br>"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
num = lines.Length;
```

The reason why you get the (somewhat cryptic) error message is because `System.Linq` apparently has an `internal` class called `Strings`.

Comment: This worked thanks. Need to wait a few more minutes before I can accept as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the following line:

```
string[] lines = Strings.Split(DT33.Text, "<br>");
```

You've added an extra 's' on to `String`. I'm guessing you're also including `System.Linq` which apparently has a private/internal class (which is inaccessible to you) called `Strings`. Hence the error message about `Strings` being inaccessible due to protection level.

You just need to change the offending line to:

```
string[] lines = DT33.Text.Split(new string[] { "<br>" },
                                 StringSplitOptions.None);
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Thought this was it but it reports this error......CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @marc11h - My fingers are faster than my brain. Fixed to use the proper overload.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split`, but your usage is conflicting with another `Strings` class that is available.

Try fully qualifying your method call.

```
string[] lines = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split(text, separator);
```

However, you should also consider using the `string.Split` instance method available for `System.String` directly. Evaluate its behavior and see if you can use it instead, as using basic BCL methods in C# is more idiomatic than using methods more or less specific to Visual Basic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx

So you might have something like

```
string[] lines =  yourText.Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
string.Split(.....)
```

rather than Strings

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to use LINQ Dynamic Query Library or System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression. You can get it from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx).

More details on ScottGu's blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)